# Redefinition of custom delete

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, macros, void-pointers

I am getting an error saying that I have redefined a function custom_delete.

header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static int unfreed_count = 0; 
#define DELETE(O) custom_delete(O,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__)

void custom_delete(void* ptr, const std::string& function_name, unsigned int line_number) {
    unfreed_count--;
    std::cout << "delete called in " + function_name + ":" << line_number << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "unfreed_count: = " << unfreed_count << std::endl << std::endl;
    free(ptr);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int* ptr = new int;
    DELETE(ptr);
}
```

This code results in the following error message upon attempted compilation:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void custom_delete(void*, const string&, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:5:6: error: redefinition of 'void custom_delete(void*, const string&, unsigned int)'
 void custom_delete(void* ptr, const std::string& function_name, unsigned int line_number) {
      ^
In file included from main.cpp:21:0:
header.h:7:6: note: 'void custom_delete(void*, const string&, unsigned int)' previously defined here
 void custom_delete(void* ptr, const std::string& function_name, unsigned int line_number) {
      ^
```

I was trying to make a custom version of delete that printed out when it was used. This was in a larger project, so I made a separate project with just these two files and got the same errors.

I tried commenting out all the code inside the `custom_delete` function. I also tried writing the prototype before the macro. I got the same error each time.

---EDIT---
I found there was another file being compiled:
header.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

// Some commented out functions
```

If I remove the `#include "header.h"` everything works. However, I eventually will need to add the functions to header.cpp. These functions need stuff that will be added to header.h. What should I do?

Comment: What happens if you move `#define DELETE(O) custom_delete(O,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__)` to be after `custom_delete`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just tried that and had the same result. :-(

Comment: Besides everything else that's wrong with this, attempting to `free()` something that was `new`ed results in undefined behavior. You cannot `free()` what's been `new`ed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have made that fix. It does not solve the problem thought.

Comment: Are you sure you copy/pasted the exact code you are trying to compile ? I've just tried to compile it and succeeded. (Added an include to malloc.h though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have include guard in your headers.

Add `#pragma once` as the first line of your `header.h`

or for more portable solution, add

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
```

as first two lines, and

```
#endif
```

as last line of the `header.h`.

Also, to avoid link errors, add `inline` keyword to declaration of your function, like `inline void custom_delete(...`

or move function implementation to `.cpp`.

Comment: I already had the header guard, I had forgotten to include it. However, adding inline solved the problem. By the way, why is the inline needed in this case?

Comment: `inline` permits you to duplicate the implementation of the function over the translation unit (i.e. `.cpp`) because the implementation shall be "known" to compiler at compile time so that compiler could actually inline the function, that is the idea. Otherwise redefinition of functions is not allowed.

Comment: @Halbort - so the code you posted wasn't the code that was causing problems. Sigh.

Comment: No the code I posted had a problem. It was missing the inline.